# How to connect an android device with ADB server using Python?

Tags: python, android, django, adb

I am able to connect an Android device with ADB *using a USB cable* but I want to connect a remote device *without a USB cable*, and not rooted also. I am running the ADB command through Python. I have been googling for 2 days and most of the resources say we can't do this. If it's not possible, please suggest other options.

Is this possible with a Python script?

Comment: please any one can give me reply ...? It's very important to me

Comment: Hi @Suryavamsham Ramakrishna could you provide the type of device? For example is it a mobile phone? Also the model? For example is it a Samsung Galaxy S21?        Lastly, can you provide a snippet of your python code?

Comment: Hi @RyanBurch Thanks for replying. The device may be any thing mobile phone (Android & ISO) or tablet. I can provide model number to python function. But the issue is while doing with emulator / USB authorization is  going on so how could I authorize remote device.